# Use Phonegap-BarcodeScanner-Plugin for scanning existing Pictures without Camera

Tags: plugins, cordova, barcode, barcode-scanner

Would it be possible, to modify the PhoneGap-BarcodeScanner-Plugin (for iOS in my case) in that way, that it can scan already existing pictures from the iPhone-Photolibrary instead of fotos taken with the camera?

Due to the fact, that it take pictures and scan them after taking, it should be very easy. But i am not an object-c-speaker, so, looking at this code, i dont understand anything :(

thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

well, sorry but i think its not possible to scan existing picture from phone library.

Comment: why not? with phonegap it is possible to select a picture from photo library for working with it. And when you have its data, you should be able to scan it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding ZBarSDK to you project

Here's link for its [download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/iPhoneSDK/ZBarSDK-1.2.dmg/download)

Check the documentation [here](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/picker.html)

Comment: Okay, thanks. But the Author of the zbar-Plugin highly recommends using ZXing instead of ZBar (without giving a special reason): [link](https://github.com/happyboredom/Zbar-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/master/README)

Comment: Yes but there will be no scanning for image from photo gallery